# r shiny interactive data frame pass to module

Tags: r, shiny, module, interactive

need a helep!

when change selectInput, table in module does not change (not reactive) as expected.

There are PROJ_RESULTS_04_202203, PROJ_RESULTS_04_202203,... table to read interactively as per the selectInput value and need to display table using the shiny module.

there is no error in codes. it runs perfectly. when change selectInput value table change in the application but not in the module.

any possible reason ?

```
library(shiny)

# Save data  tables ----
df1 <- data.frame(team=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
                 points=c(6, 14, 15, 19, 22, 25, 39, 34))

df2 <- data.frame(team=c('B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B','B', 'B'),
                 points=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))

saveRDS(df1,"PROJ_RESULTS_04_202203")
saveRDS(df2,"PROJ_RESULTS_04_202204")

# Module UI -----
data_show_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(dataTableOutput(ns("table01")))
}

# Module Server -----
data_show_Server <- function(id, df){
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 ns <- NS(id)

                 output$table01 <-
                   renderDataTable(df)
               })
}
#  UI -----

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("dynamic data input"),


                  fluidRow(
                                wellPanel(
                                  # Select year and month
                                  selectInput(
                                    inputId = "selectInput_01",
                                    label = "Year Month",
                                    choices = unique(c(202203, 202204)),
                                    selected = 202203,
                                    selectize = TRUE
                                  )
                                )),

                fluidRow(
                                hr("module"),
                                 data_show_UI("a")
                ),

                fluidRow(
                                hr("not module"),
                                dataTableOutput("table_01")
                                )


)

#  server -----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  PROJ_RESULTS_04 <- reactive({
    x <- paste0("PROJ_RESULTS_04_", input$selectInput_01)
    return(readRDS(x))

  })


output$table_01 <-
  renderDataTable(PROJ_RESULTS_04())


data_show_Server("a",df = PROJ_RESULTS_04())



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Edit:

I encountered another problem when I change `data_show_Server` module.

I want to edit df before render as follows,

```
# Module Server -----
data_show_Server <- function(id, df){
  moduleServer(id,
               function(input, output, session) {
                 ns <- NS(id)

newdf <- reactive({head(df())})
                 output$table01 <-
                   renderDataTable(newdf)
               })
}
```

now module does not show data table. problem might be in `newdf <- reactive({head(df())})`

this might be a small error but I cant find a way to solve it as I am new to R programming.

later got it worked by changing  `newdf` to  `newdf()`

````
data_show_Server <- function(id, df){ moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) { ns <- NS(id) newdf <- reactive({head(df())}) output$table01 <- renderDataTable(newdf()) }) } ```
````

Comment: Hello @Nuwan. SO is structured as an initial question followed by answers proposed by contributors possibly having each some comments. You asked a second question in an answer. That is not meant to do it so. If you need further help ask a new question or add comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve you desired result pass the `reactive` itself to the module server, i.e. without `()` and instead use `df()` with parentheses in the module server:

```
library(shiny)

# Module UI -----
data_show_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(dataTableOutput(ns("table01")))
}

# Module Server -----
data_show_Server <- function(id, df) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- NS(id)
      output$table01 <-
        renderDataTable(df())
    }
  )
}
#  UI -----

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("dynamic data input"),
  fluidRow(
    wellPanel(
      # Select year and month
      selectInput(
        inputId = "selectInput_01",
        label = "Year Month",
        choices = unique(c(202203, 202204)),
        selected = 202203,
        selectize = TRUE
      )
    )
  ),
  fluidRow(
    hr("module"),
    data_show_UI("a")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    hr("not module"),
    dataTableOutput("table_01")
  )
)

#  server -----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  PROJ_RESULTS_04 <- reactive({
    x <- paste0("PROJ_RESULTS_04_", input$selectInput_01)
    return(readRDS(x))
  })
  data_show_Server("a", df = PROJ_RESULTS_04)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As seen from the image, after doing so the data table gets updated when selecting `202204` and shows your `df2` dataset:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @stefan Now it is working, You solved my headache.